# How to turn characters to bits in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, bit

I'm just wondering if there's any method or class that can turn strings into bits directly, for example `'h'` into `'01001000'`.

More specifically a way to turn words, sentences, or whole text files into binary text.

I know that there are methods that can give the number of a character in an ascii table, e.g.

```
'h'.ord #=> 104
```

but I'm looking for a method that can convert not just individual characters but strings and possibly text files straight into a binary representation.

Comment: What does it mean for a character to be "in bits"? Define that.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: For bits I mean 1's and 0's.

Comment: I wan to know how to turn ascii characters into bits. For example:               h => 01001000

Comment: @Practical1 just single characters or a string containing multiple characters? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan I know this is late, but I mean a string containing multiple characters (i.e a sentence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
'hello'.unpack('B*')
#=> ["0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"]
#     ^^^^^^^^
#     01101000 = h
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String#ord`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-ord) gives you the ascii code. [`Integer#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) takes radix base as an argument:

```
"a".ord
=> 97
97.to_s(2)
=> "1100001"

"a".ord.to_s(2)
=> "1100001"

"a".ord.to_s(2).chars.map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
  # ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
  # 64 32 16 8  4  2  1
  #
  # 64 + 32 + 1 = 97
```

Comment: btw: The inverse (in effect) to `String#ord` would be `Integer#chr`; e.g.: `"a".ord.chr => "a"` or `'1100001'.to_i(2).chr => "a"`.

Comment: thx for your answer: `"A".ord.to_s(2)` # => "1000001"` but "A" converted to binary form (assuming ASCII) should be: `01000001` - with a leading zero. Am I missing something?